# How to trigger Jenkins agent clean-up before every job (not just workspace)?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-agent

#### What I'd like to do:

Before/after any build allocates an agent: Reset agent to a pristine state (eg restore/delete files, kill rogue processes, etc.  In other words, run some script).  **I know how to do this in one job**, I don't know how to have Jenkins trigger it **for every job of every type** without modifying them all.

#### Unsatisfactory Ways I can think of accomplishing this:

1. Enforce a pre/post step in every **AbstractProject** (old style jobs).  This is only scalable if using the [Job DSL Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/) to generate all jobs.
2. Enforce a pre/post step in every **PipelineJob**.  This is only scalable if using a Jenkins shared library (eg: `myBuild()` that encapsulates these steps).
3. Make use of the [Global Post Script plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/global-post-script/) and run a groovy script after every build.  This works, but the script runs after the agent has been released, so another build may have grabbed it already (it's too late).  Figuring out what nodes *were* allocated during the build is also [fairly complicated](https://github.com/akomakom/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/post-build-scripts.groovy)
4. Switch all agent to one-shot type (ie Docker) that require no clean-up.  This doesn't work for my use cases, but may work for someone else.
5. Periodically run a job that uses a System Groovy Script to edit all other jobs to add a "clean-up" "pre" build step if not present.  (Will not work for Pipeline jobs)

(I currently do #1 and #2)

#### Ideal Solution

Theoretical options:

1. A plugin to hook into some event (ie [WorkspaceListener.beforeUse()](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/WorkspaceListener.html#beforeUse-hudson.model.AbstractBuild-hudson.FilePath-hudson.model.BuildListener-) ) and execute something then (unfortunately, WorkspaceListener does not apply to Pipeline Jobs).  This should trigger right before an agent is used.  It gets a little complicated when an agent has multiple executors (mine don't).
2. A plugin to enforce execution of some steps, similar to "Execute builders from job X", but in every job. (also doesn't work for Pipeline jobs)
3. Assuming that I'm using [Swarm](https://plugins.jenkins.io/swarm/) for all agents, modify the swarm client to handle this logic (perform a task when an agent becomes idle).  A poor man's way would be to make the swarm client run in "one-shot" mode, in a bash loop.

#### Question:

What am I overlooking?  **Is there a better way?**

Comment: You can use [`mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html) or some permutation of to clean tbe local repo. Not sure what logic you'd use to determine a rogue process. We have many executors per node and a job may span many processes. The job executor ending should kill child processes.

Comment: @IanW apologies if I wasn't clear.  I know how to clean up the slave.  I don't know how to have it happen before every job.

Comment: When I read the question, it started "(eg `~/.m2/repository/my/org`)", so that is what I answered. Our Freestyle jobs have options " [ _ ] Prepare an environment for the run" and " [ _ ] Delete workspace before build starts" that support external commands; you can investigate.

Comment: Thank you @IanW, for helping me clarify the question. Once again, I know how to make **one job** do this.  My question is about how to make **every job** do this, always.  My Jenkins instance has over 5000 jobs of all types.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you ***could*** fiddle around in the workspace of jobs (or anywhere else on the node), but I doubt that the input field of the build triggers section ["build after other projects are built"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP8si.png) will handle your 5000 jobnames well.

And groovy whould be able to select the triggering workspace, node and job run.... the lockable-resources plugin might give the cleanup-job exclusive access ....

But you will never now for sure what any "rouge" previous job run did to your node, regardless of when to clean it up, before or after the run. It will always be more or less an estimated guess.

And the whole process will likely cause more trouble than reworking legacy jobs.

You said you don't have immutable infrastructure, but I guess you could run Docker on the hardware? If so, you should give Docker agents a chance. You will run prepared container images as your agents (on your hardware) and let Jenkins handle spinning them up in your own "clouds" (aka you node hardware). Group / name them with labels and replace our original node references with the new ones.

Here is an examplary [blog post](https://devopscube.com/docker-containers-as-build-slaves-jenkins/) describing the initial setup.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend having immutable build infrastructure, rather than trying to cleanse an existing machine running the agent. It's a better spot to be in to assert that the agent spins up exactly as the last one, rather than that it was properly cleaned. How this works is quite dependent on what you're building and what you're running it on.

I've also updated your question to reflect the preferred language of controller/agent, see https://cd.foundation/blog/2020/08/25/jenkins-terminology-changes

Comment: Thank you, @thekbb for the answer.   While it is great to have immutable infrastructure, it is not always practical.  At the time I wrote the question, I did not have access to automate things like VSphere, so I was attempting to solve the problem using the tools I did have access to.